# If the area of the cone is $150$ cm$^2$, what is the maximum volume it may hold?

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

Here is the exact question: A martini glass is a stemmed glass with an inverted cone bowl. What is the maximum possible volume of martini it can hold if the conical part has an area of 150 cm$^2$?

Comment: Total surface area of the cone or curved surface area?

Comment: The cone is defined by the radius of the base and its altitude (or by its slant height, the length from apex to rim/base).  So one constraint is the surface area (which amounts to a sector of a circle), and for this fixed area we want to maximize the volume.  Best to express the volume as a function of just one variable (using the constraint on area), and then apply standard calculus techniques to locate the maximum.

Answer (score 3):

As others have explained, we get the formula
$$V= \frac 13 πr^2 \sqrt{\left(\frac{150}{πr}\right)^2 - r^2}$$
And the suggestion was to compute $\frac{dV}{dr}$ and set it to $0$. But there is an easier way: note that if $V$ is maximised, then $V^2$ is maximised too. So you can find the optimal value of $r$ by differentiating
$$V^2= \frac 19 π^2r^4 \left[\left(\frac{150}{πr}\right)^2 - r^2\right]=\frac 19 π^2\left[\left(\frac{150}{\pi}\right)^2r^2-r^6\right]$$
and setting the result to $0$ $-$ a much easier proposition.

Comment: Very nice! :) +1

Answer (score 0):

The formulas for the volume and surface area of a right, circular cone are, respectively:

\begin{align}
V&= \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h\\
A&= \pi r\sqrt{r^2+h^2}
\end{align}

You know $A$, and you want to find the combination of $r$ and $h$ that maximizes $V$.

To do this, first solve the second equation for $h$ to obtain 
$$h=\sqrt{\left(\frac{A}{\pi r}\right)^2-r^2}$$
and insert this into the first equation. The resulting expression should now be differentiated w.r.t $r$ and set to zero (plotting reveals that, for positive values of $r$, this is indeed a maximum). The value of $r$ that satisfy this turns out to be 
$$r_{max}=5.2504\dots \text{cm}$$

Note that this was found using software (the equation you get after differentiating is *not* trivial!), so perhaps this is not the intention of the problem? Are you expected to use math software in your class?

Comment: @JeannetteJoyD.Avila Sure, but I don't see you needing to do any second derivatives? Either way, I'll update my answer.

Comment: The exact value is $\sqrt{\dfrac{50\sqrt3}{\pi}}$. See my answer for the method.

Comment: @JeannetteJoy I used a computer. See TonyK's answer for a way to find the exact value by an easier method.

Answer (score 0):

From complete question its clear that it is curved surface area.

So we have,

$\pi rl = 150$

$πr\sqrt{r^2+h^2}=150$

$\sqrt{r^2+h^2} = \frac{150}{πr}$

$r^2+h^2 = (\frac{150}{πr})^2$

$h^2 = (\frac{150}{πr})^2 - r^2$

$h = \sqrt{(\frac{150}{πr})^2 - r^2}$

Volume $=\frac 13 πr^2h$

$= \frac 13 πr^2 \sqrt{(\frac{150}{πr})^2 - r^2}$

$= \frac 13 πr \sqrt{(\frac{150r}{π})^2 - r^6}$

Find $\frac{dV}{dr}$

Using chain rule,

$\frac{dV}{dr} = \frac 13 π \left[ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{(\frac{150r}{π})^2 - r^6}} \cdot (\frac{300r}{π^2}-6r^5)\right]$

Then $\frac{dV}{dr}=0$.

$ \frac 13 π \left[ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{(\frac{150r}{π})^2 - r^6}} \cdot (\frac{300r}{π^2}-6r^5)\right]=0$

$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{(\frac{150r}{π})^2 - r^6}} \cdot (\frac{300r}{π^2}-6r^5)=0$

Hope it helps.

Comment: @JeannetteJoy Use the chain rule.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh It seems you have not tried this yourself. If you had, you'd see that it is not easy to simply "get value of r" when setting the derivative equal to zero.

Comment: @Lovsovs I want the user to try it. If you want me to do it. Then I will.