# The cone of an ice cream has an area of $30 \text{cm}^2$. What is the maximum possible volume it can contain?

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

> The cone of an ice cream has an area of $30 \text{cm}^2$.
>
> What is the maximum possible volume it can contain?

I already tried to answer this question but I'm not sure if my calculated radius is correct. Please check. If mine is incorrect, kindly point out where did I get it wrong.

\begin{align}A&=\pi rc\\
A&=30 \;\text{cm}^2\end{align}

\begin{align}
c^2 & = r^2 + h^2\\
c&= \sqrt{r^2+h^2}\\
A&=\pi r\sqrt{r^2+h^2 }\\
30&=\pi r^2 \sqrt{r^2+h^2}\\
\frac{30}{\pi r} &= \sqrt{r^2+h^2}\\
\left(\frac{30}{\pi r}\right)^2&=r^2+h^2\\
h^2&=\left(\frac{30}{\pi r}\right)^2-r^2\\
h&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{30}{\pi r}\right)^2-r^2}\end{align}

Substitute the formula

\begin{align}V&=\frac 13 \pi r^2 h\\
V&=\frac 13 \pi r^2 \sqrt{\left(\frac{30}{\pi r}\right)^2-r^2 }\end{align}

Set $dv/dr=0$

\begin{align}0&= \frac 13 \pi r^2 \sqrt{\left(\frac{30}{\pi r}\right)^2-r^2 }\\
0^2&= \left(\frac 13 \pi r^2 \sqrt{\left(\frac{30}{\pi r}\right)^2-r^2 }\right)^2\\
0&= \frac 19 π^2 r^4 \left[\left(\frac{30}{\pi r}\right)^2-r^2 \right]\\
0&= \frac 19 \pi^2 \left[\left(\frac{30r}{\pi}\right)^2-r^6 \right]\\
0&=  \frac{\pi^2}{9} \left(\frac{30^2 r^2}{\pi^2} -r^6 \right)\\
0&=  \frac 19 (30^2 r^2-r^6 )\\
\frac{r^6}{9}&= \frac{30^2 r^2}{9}\\
\sqrt{\frac{r^6}{9}}&=\sqrt{\frac{30^2 r^2}{9}}\\
\frac{r^3}{3}&= \frac{30r}{3}\\
\frac{r^3}{r}&= \frac{30(3)}{3}\\
\sqrt{r^2}&= \sqrt{\frac{30(3)}{3}}\\
r&=5.4772 \;\text{cm}\end{align}

Comment: Could you format your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) please, it's currently impossible to read

Comment: I've attempted the formatting, can you check I've not changed anything you wrote please

Comment: Related: [If the area of the cone is $150\, \text{cm}^{2}$, what is the maximum volume it may hold?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196544)

Comment: ok till $V= \cdots$, but then it is not $V=0$, rather $dV/dr=0$

Comment: I've edited it now. So... is the calculated radius wrong?

Comment: The radius is wrong. See the link provided by @Andrew . The method in the link gives the answer: $\sqrt{\dfrac{10\sqrt3}{\pi}}$